# Как выделить ссылку при переходе по ней

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Вообщем, имею полностью ajax сайт. Меню находиться в индексном файле, в него подгружается только текст. При нажатие на кнопку я хочу чтобы она была к примеру другого цвета. И при переходе по другой ссылке, принимала цвет стандартный, а то что была нажата становилось другого цвета. Ну в общем как присвоить\убрать класс на нажатой ссылке?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Допустим у нас все рабочие ссылки имеют класс: link.

Допустим, цвет активной ссылки задается классом active.

Получается:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
   $('.link').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: @avengerweb пометьте вопрос как решенный :-)

Comment: а нет не работает. Присваивается класс лишь одному, первому элементу.

Comment: Тогда приведите полный пример, т.к. по описанию не совсем понятно, чем не подходит мой пример.

Comment: <ul id="navigation">

    <li><a id="link" href="#">Главная</a></li>

    <li><a id="link" href="#news">Новости</a></li>

    <li><a id="link"  href="#register">Регистрация</a></li>

    <li><a id="link"  href="/lk/">Пусто</a></li>
 
    <li><div id="loading">Загружаю</div></li>

    </ul>

Answer (score 4):

Да все отлично [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/7F6d2/)

прекратите использовать одинаковые id!!!! что за детский сад??

Comment: зыж js код уважаемого @lampa ;)

Comment: @thunder о, благодарствую!